Zeroing deleted files / empty HDD space on Windows
I have done a bit of research into how recover deleted file tools work on NTFS under Windows. By deletion, I mean deletion while omitting the recycling bin. What I am trying to achieve is the following:

Find deleted files, and write over them.
Find all unallocated space on a drive and zero the contents. I thought that this approach would make the first objective moot. However, I have seen programs that access the MFT but succeed only to an extent. The MFT seems to hold on to deleted entries for a while (with a flag), then removes them.

I code in C# .NET and was wondering how to approach the challenge of accessing any space on a given drive that does not have active file data, and zeroing it.
I feel that looking at the source code of a defragmentation tool may help, but I still do not know how to access unallocated space directly to manipulate it.
EDIT: Please note that this question is not about formatting drives.

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1373948/how-to-wipe-unallocated-disk-space-in-windows, but if you're asking about how to do this in C# you should ask on StackOverflow.

@HashimAziz: Thank you! I was unaware of this tool and suspect that most people aren't either. yOu should post your comment as an answer. The only remaining aspect which is unaddressed in that answer is one or more blocks on SSDs that the OS is not aware of.

Note that there are tons of secure deletion tools out there, so unless you really want to write a program, no need to.
